# Choosing & saving your own hotkeys on multiple forms

Tags: c#, .net, windows, forms, keycode

Currently I have two buttons: Start and Stop. Both can be triggered by a global hotkey.
Here is the code for the start button (same as the stop button, this code is on Form1):

```
if (keyPressed == Key.F1 && btnStart.Enabled == true)
{
    // do stuff in here
}
```

On Form2, the user should set hotkeys for the buttons on Form1 themselves.

The process should be as following:

1. Show the user the current hotkey (F1 for start & F2 for stop) eg with a label
2. A button to change the hotkey eg 'Press this button and after that, click the key you would like on your keyboard' -> 'The new hotkey is now F5!'
3. Save the new hotkey in a string (or similar)
4. Save the hotkey so that after the application has been restarted, the hotkeys selected by the user are active & and no longer F1 and F2.

My idea was something like this:

```
string userhotkey;
if (keyPressed == userhotkey && btnStart.Enabled == true) 
{
    // do stuff
}
```

My question is how can I realize that the user can choose their own hotkeys on Form2 and apply them to Form1.

Comment: And your question is...?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare static variables in Program class:

```
namespace TestNamespace {
    static class Program {
        public static String HotkeyStart; //or not string
        public static String HotkeyStop; //or not string

        [STAThread]
        static void Main() {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new TestForm());
        }
    }
}
```

They could be reached from any form or class

I recommend you to store hotkey info in class as uint or Keys

I use something like that

```
        public uint Hotkey = 0;
        public uint Modifier = 0;
```

```
        public void SetHotkey(uint key) {
            Hotkey = key & 0xffff;
            Modifier = Convert.ToUInt32(String.Concat(Convert.ToString(key >> 16 & 7, 2).PadLeft(3, '0').Reverse()), 2) | 0x4000;
            RegisterHotkey(true);
        }
```

```
        public override string ToString() {
                String ret = "";
                if ((Modifier & 1) == 1)
                    ret += "Alt+";
                if ((Modifier & 2) == 2)
                    ret += "Ctrl+";
                if ((Modifier & 4) == 4)
                    ret += "Shift+";
                ret += (Keys)Hotkey;
            if (IsActive) {
                return ret;
            }
            else {
                return ret+ "(Not active)";
            }
        }
```

This format (Hotkey+Modifier) I use with

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")] 
public static extern 
bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, uint fsModifiers, int vk);
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I put 'Key.F1' into a string so the 'keyPressed' method can read it?

Comment: @HvRibbecK, I recommend you use simple class with `Keys hotkey` or `uint hotkey`, override `ToString()` method and call it when you want to display hotkey info